# AS3 Child is null after being added to stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, null, addchild

sI have created a child and added it to a movieclip, but when I access its properties in another function, Animate throws an Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

The child has a listener added and removed with no difficulty, and can be removed from the Display List just fine with removeChild, but apparently has no other properties associated with it (x, y, etc). Its as if the child has been added to the display list, but has no other associated properties?

The child is cast as a MovieClip, and I tried adding a listener (ADDED_TO_STAGE) to ensure the child was available on the stage as a display object before accessing its properties. However, no luck.

I have other situations with identical code in my game that seem to work fine. I'm not an expert, but I'm also not new to ActionScript, and this one is baffling me...

The code that creates the child:

```
function createNPCtargets():void
{
    for ( var i:int=0 ; i<= npcs -1 ; i++ )
    {
        var NPCtarget:MovieClip = new target_mc;
        overlay_mc.addChild(NPCtarget);
        NPCtarget.name = "target_" + i;
        NPCtarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireShot);
    }
}
```

The code that throws the error (npcObject is fine):

```
function moveNPC():void
{
    for (var i:int=0 ; i<= npcs -1; i++ )
    {
       overlay_mc.getChildByName("target_" + i).x = npcObject.x;
       overlay_mc.getChildByName("target_" + i).y = npcObject.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you add `trace(overlay_mc.getChildByName("target_" + i));` inside this loop? Does it find object at all ?

Comment: Good idea 3vilguy, I actually tried this before posting. Oddly, it traces the object itself with no issues, but the second I add a .x (or any other property) to the end of the line, it throws a runtime error... so it seems to find the object with no trouble, just can't access any of its properties.

Comment: Weirdz if that works, how about  casting it as DisplayObject and check if it's not null. And you sure 'npcObject' is not null?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is but you might look at keeping the Movieclips in an array, may actually be more performant if you are calling this update function a lot.

```
var npcs:Array = [];
function createNPCtargets():void
{
    for ( var i:int=0 ; i<= npcs -1 ; i++ )
    {
        var NPCtarget:MovieClip = new target_mc;
        overlay_mc.addChild(NPCtarget);
        NPCtarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireShot);
        npcs.push(NPCtarget);
    }
}

function moveNPC():void
{
    for (var i:int=0 ; i<= npcs.length ; i++ )
    {
       npcs[i].x = npcObject.x;
       npcs[i].y = npcObject.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Definitely calling the update function a lot, its part of the main game loop. I gave your code a shot, and a different error popped up this time: Error#1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

This leads me to believe that the main loop is causing the issue: the moveNPC() function is being called before the array can be populated with the children, causing the error. This is weird though, since I tested whether it was added to stage first, and the children are indeed there, just null.

Comment: The solution with the array is the way to go, getChildByName is very slow. Like 3vilguy mentioned above - have you tried to trace your npcObject ? Maybe this is the one that is causing problems ? Because your movieclips should be accessible by now